# How to purge deleted objects from s3 bucket (w versioning)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

I have an S3 bucket (w versioning) which contains almost 10m deleted objects with total ~10TB and I want to clean it up.
All of these objects are in pair with a delete marker.

For testing a lifecycle policy found in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-conceptual-ex6
, created a bucket with versioning, added some objects and then deleted one of them.

Enabled a lifecycle policy as shown in the picture, but so far (>2 days later) nothing happened, the deleted object still exists.

[image: Lifecycle policy]

Did I do something wrong with the configuration?